# How do I get all hot corners in Ubuntu 17.10 and later with GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome-shell

I want Ubuntu to **Window Spread** as I move my mouse to lower left corner.

I want this sort of option.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use this Gnome Shell extension called [CustomCorner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1037/customcorner/).

It doesn't fully replace all options one had with compiz, but it's a start.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal: Ctrl + Alt + T

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell enable-hot-corners true
```

It's that simple!

Comment: This works but how do I configure the actions for the corners?

Comment: @AlbinStigo Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @AlbinStigo the point is that you explained only how to *enable* the hot corners, but how to configure them? e.g. how can I associated a certain action to a certain corner?

Comment: use gnome extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1037/customcorner/

Comment: This answer only lets you enable (or disable) the Activities overview hot corner, doesn't really help you achieve what the question asks for. For that purpose your last comment is useful, but that is already mentioned in the answer by @joschi.